# Given an aws-lambda, how can I change the cloudwatch rule associated with it using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, serverless-framework

I've seen the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#id26), but I can't find how to change the scheduled event. Here's the example on `serverless.yml`:

```
schedule_customer_processing:
    handler: fetch-downloadable-client-data/adyen/schedule_customer_processing.schedule
    events:
     - schedule: rate(15 minutes)
```

Using boto3, how can I change the rate of the schedule programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from this example in my [blog](https://yorodm.github.io)

```py
REGULAR_SCHEDULE = 'rate(20 minutes)'
WEEKEND_SHEDULE = 'rate(1 hour)'
RULE_NAME = 'My Rule'

def reschedule_event():
    """
    Cambia la planificación de la lambda, para que descanse los findes :D
    """
    sched = boto3.client('events')
    current = sched.describe_rule(Name=RULE_NAME)
    if is_weekend() and 'minutes' in current['ScheduleExpression']:
        sched.put_rule(
            Name=RULE_NAME,
            ScheduleExpression=WEEKEND_SCHEDULE,
        )
    if not is_weekend and 'hour' in current['ScheduleExpression']:
        sched.put_rule(
            Name=RULE_NAME,
            ScheduleExpression=REGULAR_SCHEDULE,
        )
```

Calling `shed.put_rule` will allow you to change the event schedule.